# read null values and return null from a xml file C# win froms

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration version="45.2012.4.23" xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
  <description>example.com</description>
  <reading />
  <connection>
    <sourceId>452342341</sourceId>  
    <organization/>
    <field>*</field>
  </connection>
  <source>
    <sourceId>452342341</sourceId>
    <connectionContext>
      <id />
      <name>testing</name>
      <description />
      <contextType>Section</contextType>      
      <organization/>
      <field>Demo Field</field>
      <section>testing</section>
      <subSection />
    </connectionContext>
    <Mode>Section</Mode>
    <activity>bell Testing</activity>
  </source>
</configuration>
```

I want to read this xml and display data in the `textboxes` of windows form.

When i select the xml file in a listbox I want to read first set of data from `connection` tag and  second set of data from `connectionContext` tag, display the values in the textboxes.

The problem when there is a null value the below code is not working???

```
 private void DisplayFile(string path)
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
            var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            var conn = doc.Root.Element(ns + "connection");

            textBox1.Text = conn.Element(ns + "sourceId").Value;
            textBox3.Text = conn.Element(ns + "description").Value;
            textBox4.Text = conn.Element(ns + "uri").Value;
            textBox5.Text = conn.Element(ns + "username").Value;

            var conn1 = doc.Root.Element(ns + "connectionContext");

            textBox7.Text = conn1.Element(ns + "field").Value;
            textBox8.Text = conn1.Element(ns + "bellName").Value;
            textBox9.Text = conn1.Element(ns + "id").Value;
            textBox10.Text = conn1.Element(ns + "bellboreName").Value;    
        }
```

Error message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at this field `(ns + "field").Value;`

Comment: Could you please define what's not working? Some kind of exception? Also, the 'ns1' is not defined in your code. Where do you create it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Wouter de Kort: edited question with error message.

Comment: Is your conn1 actually pointing to the correct element? Is your code working when you remove the textBox7 line?

Comment: @ Wouter de Kort : yes, it's. If i remove  textBox7, it works but i'm having a same problem at  textBox8.

Comment: @KarthikRANGARAJ no, it isn't. I've run your code and in the debugger you can see that conn1 is empty. As yamen answers, this is because you have to go one level deeper.

Comment: @ Wouter de Kort: I forgot about `source`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connectionContext` sits under `source` not under the document root, so you want to change this:

```
var conn1 = doc.Root.Element(ns + "connectionContext");
```

To this:

```
var conn1 = doc.Root.Element(ns + "source").Element(ns + "connectionContext");
```

Or alternatively, allowing a bit more flexibility in the schema:

```
var conn1 = doc.Descendants(ns + "connectionContext").First();
```